# LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher is not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, rx-java2, android-livedata

I am trying to create a `LiveData` object from an RxJava2 `Observable` using `LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher`. However, while the LiveData object is being created (from my ViewModel), it never fires when being observed (from my Fragment).

Here's a basic example. For comparison, I have included the alternative way of getting this data from an Observable into LiveData (by subscribing to the Observable).

```
class MainFragmentViewModel : ViewModel() {

    val liveData1: LiveData<List<Int>>
    val liveData2: MutableLiveData<List<Int>> = MutableLiveData()

    private val disposeBag = CompositeDisposable()

    init {
        val obs: Observable<List<Int>> = Observable.just(listOf(1, 2, 3))

        liveData1 = LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher { obs }

        obs.subscribe { liveData2.value = it }.addTo(disposeBag)
    }
}
```

```
class MainFragment : Fragment() {

    private val vm: MainFragmentViewModel by viewModel()

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()

        vm.liveData1.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            Timber.d("The liveData1 list has count ${it.count()}")
        })
        vm.liveData2.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            Timber.d("The liveData2 list has count ${it.count()}")
        })
    }
}
```

Logcat now contains only this:

`D/MainFragment$onStart: The liveData2 list has count 3`

In other words, using `LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher` doesn't do anything, while subscribing to the Observable directly and updating the `LiveData`'s value works fine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that method but the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LiveDataReactiveStreams.html#fromPublisher(org.reactivestreams.Publisher%3CT%3E) mentions "when the livedata becomes active". So perhaps you have to activate it in some way?

Comment: As I understand it, this is bound to the lifecycle of the Fragment, so it should automatically become (in)active.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher` takes `Publisher` as a parameter. You must convert the `Observable` to a `Publisher`. For example:

```
val obs2 = obs.toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER)
```

2. and the correct syntax is:

```
liveData1 = LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher(obs)
```

Comment: Thanks, point 2 fixed this for me (I had already tried this with a Flowable before, but that didn't work with the wrong syntax).